# How to send query value without URL encoding in go-lang?

Tags: go

Example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    u, err := url.Parse("http://bing.com/search?q=dotnet")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    u.Scheme = "https"
    u.Host = "google.com"
    q := u.Query()
    q.Set("q", "golang../")
    u.RawQuery = q.Encode()
    fmt.Println(u)
}
```

Output: `https://google.com/search?q=golang..%2F` here "/" is encoded to "%2F"  what to do if we don't what this and want something like `https://google.com/search?q=golang../` I tried to find a lot on google but didn't get anything

Comment: Why would you want to assemble an invalid URL?

Comment: %2F didn't work as intended if manually put "/" it works as intended

Answer (score 2):

Set the raw query to what you need, not to the encoded value:

```
u, err := url.Parse("http://bing.com/search?q=dotnet")
if err != nil {
   log.Fatal(err)
}
u.Scheme = "https"
u.Host = "google.com"
u.RawQuery = fmt.Sprintf("q=golang../")
fmt.Println(u)
```

Comment: the above code is just an example for the same code I used in my main code and I have undefined params but defined payloads which I need to send as a value in those query params. so this solution is not applicable.

Answer (score 1):

So I Found an Answer to this here the code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    u, err := url.Parse("http://bing.com/search?q=dotnet")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    u.Scheme = "https"
    u.Host = "google.com"
    q := u.Query()
    q.Set("q", "golang../")
    u.RawQuery = q.Encode()
    decoded,err:=url.QueryUnescape(q.Encode())
    u.RawQuery= decoded
    if err != nil {
        return
    } 
    fmt.Println(u)
}
```

had to use `url.QueryUnescape`